# JAX-RS enabling CORS (Access-Control-Allow-Origin) on Glassfish 4

Tags: glassfish, http-headers, jax-rs, cors

I am working in JAVA EE7, JAX-RS 2.0 Glassfish 4 is my SERVER.
I Want to work on CORS to enable Ajax Requests comming out of my domain.
I know that I need to make my server enabling it. And I did it in PHP. like the following code:

```
 <?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization");
```

but when I tried to do the same thing I always get an error message like that
["this is a screenshot"](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y4neexf5kjuwj6s/Capture.PNG).
So I've tried to modify the sever http response with many ways...

And this is my code , server side , I used a filer/provider:

```
@Provider
@CORSBinding 
public class Filter implements  ContainerRequestFilter{
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext request) throws IOException {
    request.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    request.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization"); 
    if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        System.out.println("OPTIONS is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    if (request.getMethod().equals("GET")) {
        System.out.println("GET is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
        System.out.println("POST is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    if (request.getMethod().equals("DELETE")) {
        System.out.println("DELETE is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    if (request.getMethod().equals("PUT")) {
        System.out.println("PUT is requested!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }       
}
}
```

But it seems like all blocked by a "firewall security" provided by Glassfish4 server.
here is my simple code javascript:

```
<script>
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/CV/api/v2/posts");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'a');
xhr.send();
</script>
```

I even added an other filter using the @Prematching annotation to update the request from OPTIONS TO POST ... but I always lose my headers that I have sent within it (I mean within POST request).

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
 public class HttpMethodOverrideEnabler implements ContainerRequestFilter {
 @Override
 public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    containerRequestContext.setMethod("POST");

    containerRequestContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    containerRequestContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Authorization");
    containerRequestContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Authorization");

    String override = containerRequestContext.getHeaders().getFirst( "X-HTTP-Method-Override");
    if (override != null) {
        containerRequestContext.setMethod(override);
    }
}
```

I knew that Glassfish3 had not the support for CORS and ("https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-16049) they said that they will fix it with JEE7. 
This is the whole story...
so how can I do the CORS with this JEE7 using Glassfish server and JAX-RS2.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [ContainerResponseFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerResponseFilter.html) not [ContainerRequestFilter](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/latest/jersey/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) as you want to add those headers into response and not to the request. For example:

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.HEADER_DECORATOR)
public class AccessControlResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        final MultivaluedMap<String,Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();

        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location, Content-Disposition");
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback .
It did not work in my case... I used the Debug ,it's already changed To an OPTIONS method .
I can't take any header , because OPTIONS have no header ... there a Firewall I think that is preventing me from getting a POST reques

Answer (score 4):

You have to use the **2** **filters** the First because Chrome and other Browsers modify the headers for security purpose, and the second is to add the headers to response. So use **ContainerResponseFilter** and **ContainerRequestFilter**. it works fine with me Good luck!

Comment: For your Ajax request u need only to add this line
        headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: I have been researching this and i have found so many varying responses I am completely confused.  From your answer listed above are you saying the `public class HttpMethodOverrideEnabler implements` will implement both the ContainerResponseFilter  and the ContainerRequestFilter?